# Why is this regulator circuit unstable?

Tags: ldo, linear-regulator

I'm trying to use a LDO with higher current (5 A in my case) than what it's rated for. I derived for this the following circuit

[image: LDO higher current]

V is a noisy voltage source between 16 and 22 V (mainly 50 Hz 1 Vpp ripple).

I put R5 to unsure a minimum of 100 mΩ of ESR to any capacitive load, as the datasheet requires an ESR strictly between 100 and 400 mΩ and a minimum of 10 uF of capacitive load.

I simulated it with LTspice but I had to switch the LM2931 to an LM2941 because TI didn't provide any spice model for the first one. With a load of 3 Ω (the output is 15 V), the circuit was stable. But when I built it for real, there was about 40 mVpp of oscillation at 1 MHz.

As I'm not experienced with compensation, I tried putting 100 nF between random nodes. The only place where it seemed to help was between the collector of Q3 and ground, but I had to put a massive 470 uF to get oscillations under 1 mVpp.

I must have modified the feedback loop somehow, but I don't know what to do to correct this problem. I think the capacitor at the collector of Q3 is only filtering this oscillation, Q1/Q2 acting as capacitance multipliers.

I'm not sure either about why this oscillation wasn't visible in the simulation. Maybe it is because I didn't use the same regulator and instead used an LM2931, or maybe it is because of parasitic capacitance and inductance in the real circuit that weren't taken into account.

Is there a way to make this circuit always stable, without knowing all the internal working of the LM2931, but knowing that this circuit would normally always be stable if we removed the bypass transistors?

EDIT: There is a good reason I need an LDO here: the input voltage swings between 16.5 V and 22 V, and I need a 15 V output. I'm well aware of power dissipation hence HS1 and HS2. I'm using a linear regulator because I'm concerned about noise and I do not have the skills yet to design with a switching regulator. I'm aware it would be a better solution overall if I could manage it.

Comment: When you built it did you have bypass capacitors on the input? What does the ground look like?

Comment: No, I built it on a breadboard, and the voltage source is a Korad KA3005P. Strangely, I tried to add input capacitance and the circuit oscillated crazily at 0.5Vpp.

Comment: Thats a problem right there, you have 10pf crostalk between all the nodes, 10's mΩ of contact resistance (if it's making good contact) and extra inductance. I'd solder that thing up

Comment: Like this: https://computerhistory.org/blog/an-analog-life-remembering-jim-williams/

Comment: @VoltageSpike I'll try that as soon as possible. Why do you think adding 100n at the input made things awfully worse?

Comment: @JonasDaverio Because 100n was not nearly enough. Start with proper input and output capacitance on the regulator. Make it work without the current booster. Then start adding things around it.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I tried it without the current booster and it is stable. There is naturally about 10 to 100uF of capacitance at the voltage source I'm using, but I guess there is too much resistance and inductance in the way. I'll try adding capacitance

Comment: I tried adding 470uF at either pin for of the LM2931 or the other side of R4 and it made things much worse in either case (going from 50mVpp to 600mVpp). I'll try again with solder joint and perfboard instead of breadboard.

Comment: Why is the arrow for "V" pointing downwards?

Comment: @Andyaka It's the convention in my country.

Comment: I believe that might be the convention for electric fields rather than voltages. You are showing a voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka This is beside the point anyway. But I can assure you that in a big part of Europe, arrows are used to show voltages.

Comment: Aside from the other valid comments, you’ve got quite a bit of added gain, maybe try adding a base resistor in the low k ohms to Q3. For simulations to work well you may need to whack the system with an impulse to see the instability.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I've just tried it and it made things worse. Besides, this increases the drop out voltage which goes against the whole purpose of the circuit. I'm tending towards VoltageSpikes' idea, but I'll have to try this tomorrow.

Comment: The most likely problem here is excess voltage gain, from cascading two stages of transistors around a control loop that's already compensated for its own gain alone. Breadboard capacitances are a fraction of transistor capacitances, they likely aren't participating here. Wiring inductance maybe. Q3 needs emitter degeneration to limit its gain (and limit some short-circuit current!!), and probably an R+C across its B-C.

Comment: Since you lose thermal overload protection and overcurrent protection anyway, why not just use a voltage reference, one or two op-amps, and your big pass transistors?  Or use a switching module.

Comment: So that no one has to reverse-engineer it, what is your target output voltage?  Have you considered how much heat you need to get out of your pass transistors, and compared the expense and size of your heat sinks with the expense and size of a switching supply?

Comment: (Depending on voltage and current limits (oh well, probably not where *LDO* is *needed*), a power *resistor* works reliably as a bypass.)

Comment: All the world uses arrows for voltages but, the most positive end is usually where the arrow is. Try a 10 ohm emitter resistor for Q3.

Comment: @Jonas In addition to other comments, [PNP (LDO) regulators have well-known stability problems](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/190152/330261). The first question I have is: *"Do you really need an LDO for a variable output voltage regulator here?"* Start there. If so, then this gets to your added Q1 and Q2 arrangement in conjunction with a PNP device. I'm not sure why an LDO is needed here. Is there a clear reason?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work at all without input capacitance. The oscillations you saw with input capacitance added are a symptom of other problems, i.e. adding the capacitance doesn't make anything worse - it makes it easier to identify the real problem, if anything.

Q1 and Q2 are intended to work as current sources, to bypass excessive current around the regulator. They should have high positive output impedance, especially at AC. I don't think that's the case.

The circuit you show synthesizes a *high source impedance* for the regulator itself - it's effectively a current source. I'm not sure that there's any modern integrated voltage regulator that will work well when fed from even a current source *and* without any bypass capacitance on the input. No wonder it oscillates.

Instead, use a circuit where the bypass current is proportional to the regulator *output* current. That way, the regulator "sees" a proportionally higher load impedance, and otherwise can do its job. Bypassing based on the regulator input current only works at DC - and really at DC. Above DC, it synthesizes an inductor in front of the regulator (!). Limiting the bandwidth of the "front sensing" bypass as you have it might still work but it might be hard to keep it from motorboating.

I'd try something like the below. The regulator should probably still deal with the majority of AC load current, so the current bypass amplifiers can have their bandwidth suitably limited to e.g. 1/10th of the bandwidth of the regulator, to ensure stability.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUU81p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Don't try putting it together on the breadboard. This needs a PCB from the get-go, or assemble it in the air over a ground plane (solid copper-clad laminate).

Using mosfets as pass devices is advisable, since they don't suffer from thermal runaway. For thermal protection, the mosfets and the regulator should be thermally bonded - put them all close together on a heatsink. **Do not** try running it under load without a heatsink. Even with mosfets it's still risky.

Current protection is inherent in current scaling: once the regulator U1 starts to limit current, the bypass network will not increase its output current anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "The oscillations you saw with input capacitance added are a symptom of other problems."?

Comment: I've just tried adding a resistor between the base of Q3 and the input of the regulator, which should make the current inside the regulator proportional to the one in Q1/2. This didn't change anything.

Comment: @JonasDaverio What you're doing makes perfect sense at DC. Except your problems are *not* at DC! In AC, it matters quite a bit whether the current is sensed in front or in the back of the regulator.